# Pandas: cross join with multiple conditions

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, cross-join

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM
      table_1
    CROSS JOIN
      table_2
    WHERE
      table_1.f1 >= table_2.f1001 
      AND (
        table_1.f1 < table_2.f1002
        OR table_2.f1002 IS NULL
      )
```

Is it possible to implement this using Pandas, for example with `pd.merge(how='cross')`? Suppose we have two dataframes `table_1` and `table_1`, and we need to do a cross join according to the conditions below:

```
table_1.f1 >= table_2.f1001 AND (table_1.f1 < table_2.f1002 OR table_2.f1002 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Just wondering if a cross join is necessary here; the SQL engine could be more performant without the cross join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like

```
out = pd.merge(table_1, table_2,how='cross')
out = out[out['f1'].ge(out['f1001']) & (out['f1'].lt(out['f1001']) | table_2['f1002'].isna())]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge` and `query`:

```
out = pd.merge(table_1, table_2, how='cross') \
        .query("(f1 >= f1001) & ((f1 < f1002) | f1002.isna())")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.merge(df, on='cid', suffixes=('1','2')).query('qid1 < qid2')
```

something like that , use `query` after `merge`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).